# multilingual  font in gimp (ubuntu linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, gimp, multilingual

I have some hindi fonts in my linux (they even work in vim, when I try to to view some downloaded hindi webpages).
    Now, in gimp, it does show various multilingual fonts (hindi as well as others). However, when I try to use them, it displays only english text :(

How do I use multilingual fonts in gimp?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried entering text in the appropriate language?

Comment: hmmm, not sure what you mean. But I did select the appropriate "font" from the text toolbar. tried various non-english fonts.  My keyboard is english, so I assume it should do some phonetic conversion like most multi-language editors?

Comment: Did you invoke your IME?

Comment: note that the small rectangular "icons" to the left of the font name in the menu, are displayed correctly. Not sure if they are images.

Comment: just searched that IME is 'input method editor' :). I dont know gimp has one. could you please explain a little bit how to invoke it?

Comment: got it!  basically, I have to use a different editor and then copy paste....  thanks, if you could make it an asnwer i will accept it

Comment: I would never make that my answer because it's a silly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GIMP does not transliterate text; use a IME if you want to input text in an alphabet your keyboard does not support.